# Autopopulate documents and subdocuments in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate, auto-populate

I'm using NodeJs & I want to know how I can autopopulate documents and theirs subdocuments in mongodb, I use 'AUTOPOPULATE' of https://plugins.mongoosejs.io/plugins/autopopulate, but, this only autopopulate the first documents of schema but not their subdocuments.

Than you.